# возврат вложенного словаря из функции

Tags: python

Возможно ли вернуть написать функцию, которая будет возвращать вложенный словарь исходя из аргументов?

Например:

```
def foo(key):
    d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 3, 'e': 4}, }
    return d[key]

foo(['c']['d'])
```

Я ожидаю получить:

`3`

Я получаю:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Я понимаю, что можно возвращать весь словарь, или захардкодить возврать конкретной части словаря, но это все крайне не гибко

Answer (score 2, accepted):

само `['c']['d']` синтаксическая ошибка. поэтому придётся передавать список `['c','d']` и в цикле или рекурсивно решать задачу. Например так:

```
def foo(key,d):
    while len(key):
        d = d[key[0]]
        key = key[1:]

    return d

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 3, 'e': 4}, }
print(foo(['c','d'],d))
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае проще возвращать весь словарь, и к возвращенному значению уже обращаться по индексам: `foo()['c']['d']` - это очень даже гибко.

Другой вариант - передавать в функцию другую функцию, которая будет брать нужное значение (или вообще выполнять какие-то произвольные вычисления от исходной структуры данных):

```
def foo(key):
    d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 3, 'e': 4}, }
    return key(d)

print(foo(lambda x: x['c']['d']))
```

Так например работают функции сортировки по произвольному ключу:

```
d = [dict(a=5), dict(a=3), dict(a=10)]
d.sort(key=lambda x: x['a'])
print(d)  # [{'a': 3}, {'a': 5}, {'a': 10}]
```